# Boost.Program_options: Custom validator with state

Tags: c++, boost, command-line-interface, boost-program-options

I would like to write a custom validator for command line options that can take a value among a set of allowed values, e.g. for options such as

```
--animal arg     Allowed values: cat, dog, bird
```

For this, I defined a new type, `RestrictedIdentifierOption`:

```
class RestrictedIdentifierOption
{
public:
    using ValueType = std::pair<std::string, boost::any>;
    using ValueContainer = std::vector<ValueType>;
    explicit RestrictedIdentifierOption(const ValueContainer& allowedValues);
private:
    friend void validate(
        boost::any& v,
        const std::vector<std::string>& values,
        RestrictedIdentifierOption* option,
        int);
private:
    ValueContainer m_allowedValues;
};
```

and I overloaded `validate()`, as per the [documentation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/doc/html/program_options/howto.html#id-1.3.31.6.7):

```
void validate(
    boost::any& v,
    const std::vector<std::string>& values,
    RestrictedIdentifierOption* option,
    int)
{
    ...
}
```

Finally, I declare an option:

```
auto option = boost::make_shared<bpo::option_description>(
    "animal,a",
    new bpo::typed_value<RestrictedIdentifierOption>(new RestrictedIdentifierOption({ { "cat", 1 }, { "dog", 2 }, { "bird", 3 } })),
    "Allowed values: cat, dog, bird");
```

*(Nevermind the memory leaks here, this isn't the point.)*

I naively expected that the `option` argument in `validate()` would be set to the instance I created, however it is always equal to `nullptr`.

Is what I'm trying to do unreasonable? Can a custom validator can have a state at all with Boost.Program_options?